# Android Studio command not found

Tags: android, flutter, command

bash: flutter: command not found
I am getting that error everytime in android studio while ı was trying to write a command in android studio's terminal

Comment: Did you add flutter to your path?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Comment: yes ı add paths

Comment: my issue is on android studio not on MacOs

Comment: please help to solve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.